# Make a form View read-only for specific user groups from front-end in Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8, readonly, formview, usergroups

Is it possible to change the attributes of form view for specific user groups in form view tag, like in form tag, readonly="{('user_group','=','some_group')}">

I need to make a form view read-only for s specific user group but only from front-end. Records are updated from code by that user belonging to that specific user group from back-end. and if i disable updating the records of that model by that user group in my security file, that user is not able to modify the records even from back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is by defining a new group that have only read access on that model and add to that user you will save a lot of typing and a lot of your time.

Because what you really asking is to remove edit write for a specific user.